# How do you create a chart in Stimulsoft on grouped data?

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a data returning in a data set that looks like this:

```
Department 1    Product Name    Units
Department 1    Product Name    Units
Department 2    Product Name    Units
Department 2    Product Name    Units
Department 3    Product Name    Units
Department 3    Product Name    Units
```

I have added a Group Band that will group by Department and in the group footer band a summary that will sum units by Department.

I want to show a bar chart with the Department as the argument and the Units as the value.  But all I get in the report is each record repeated in the chart, i.e. not grouped by Department.   Do I need to define a relationship and use that as argument in the chart series?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `AutoSeries` properties (under Series tab) in order to get your data grouped by something [image: Chart with data grouped thanks to AutoSeries] This way you would have a different serie for each different value you used on your `Auto Series Key Data Column`